# Random Data Generator integers and Characters

Tags: java, netbeans

I have to Create a  RandomDataGenerator. The code I have kind of works, but I am having trouble with some parts of it. The fist issue I am having is with the integers. this is what I get when I run it:
run:

What do you want to generate?
i = integer, d = double, c = char

i

How many integers do you want?

10

Choose low value for your integer:

3

Choose high value for your integer:

7

Integers:

4
3
6
6
6
5
2
3
5
6

It gives me the 10 numbers, but it is not supposed to go lower than 3.

The other issue I'm having is with the characters this is what I get

run:
What do you want to generate?
i = integer, d = double, c = char

c

How many characters do you want?

5

Choose low limit for your character:

C

Choose high limit for your character:

S

P
false

how can I fix this problems?

```
package javaapplication5;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class JavaApplication5 {


private static int a;


public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println("What do you want to generate?  ");
    System.out.println("i = integer, d = double, c = char" );
    char i, d, c; 
    int low_int = 0,high_int = 0, quant_int = 0; 
    double low_double = 0, high_double = 0, quant_double = 0; 
    char low_char = 0, high_char = 0, quant_char = 0; 
    int result = 0; 
    String input; 

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
String A= in.next();

int largo = A.length();
char select []= new char [largo];


   select[a]=A.charAt(a);

 for(int q=0; q<largo;q++){
 if (select[q]=='i') {
    System.out.println( " How many integers do you want? ");

    Scanner Integerswanted = new Scanner(System.in);
String B= in.next();

        quant_int = Integer.parseInt(B); 

        System.out.println( " Choose low value for your integer: "); 
       Scanner LoVa = new Scanner(System.in);
String LV= in.next();
        low_int = Integer.parseInt(LV);


       System.out.println( " Choose high value for your integer: ");
        Scanner HiVa = new Scanner(System.in);
String hV= in.next(); 
       high_int = Integer.parseInt(hV); 
       System.out.println( " Integers: ");
       int random_generator = JavaApplication5.random_generator(quant_int, low_int, high_int); 
       int s = random_generator;
       if(s>low_int && s<high_int){


       }


 } 

 else if (select[q]=='d'){
     System.out.println( " How many doubles do you want? "); 

    Scanner DoublesWanted = new Scanner(System.in);
String R= in.next();

        quant_double = Double.parseDouble(R); 

        System.out.println(" Choose low value for your double: "); 
        Scanner LoDo = new Scanner(System.in);
String LD= in.next();
low_double = Double.parseDouble(LD); 


System.out.println(" Choose high value for your double: "); 
Scanner HiDo = new Scanner(System.in);
String HD= in.next();
        high_double = Double.parseDouble(HD); 
        System.out.println( " Doubles: ");
        double random_generator = JavaApplication5.random_generator(quant_double, low_double,         high_double); 
        double k = random_generator; 


     }
 else if (select[q]=='c'){
      System.out.println( " How many characters do you want? ");
      Scanner CharWanted = new Scanner(System.in);
String Cw= in.next();
        quant_char = A.charAt(0); 

       System.out.println( " Choose low limit for your character: "); 
       Scanner LoCh = new Scanner(System.in);
String LC= in.next();
        low_char = A.charAt(0); 

        System.out.println( " Choose high limit for your character: ");
          Scanner HiCh = new Scanner(System.in);
String HC= in.next();
        high_char = A.charAt(0); 

        char random_generator = JavaApplication5.random_generator(quant_char, low_char, high_char); 
        char e = random_generator; 

 } }}
public static int random_generator(int quant, int low, int high){ 



    Random rand_num = new Random(); 
    int return_int = 0; 
    for(int z = low; z <= quant + 2 ; z++) 

    System.out.println(rand_num.nextInt(high) + 1 ); 
    return return_int; 
} 

public static double random_generator(double quant, double low, double high){ 
    Random rand_num = new Random(); 
    double return_double = 0; 
    for(double z = low; z <quant + 2; z++) {
    System.out.println(rand_num.nextDouble() + low ); 
    }
    return return_double; 

} 

public static char random_generator(char quant, char low, char high){ 
    String [] abecedario = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", 
"K", "L", "M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W", "X","Y","Z" };

    int Rand_num = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 26 ) ;

System.out.println( abecedario[Rand_num] );Random 
    rand_num = new Random(); 
    char return_char = 0; 
    for(double z = low; z < quant + 1; z++) 
    System.out.println(abecedario[Rand_num].equals(high));  
    return return_char; 
} 
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your real working code?

Answer (score 0):

For the integer, you should use:

```
rand_num.nextInt(high - low) + high;
```

For the Character, you should use the same thing except you need to typecast it to a character after you find the random integer.

```
(char)rand_num.nextInt(high - low) + high;
```